# bootstrap data-toggle="tab" - how to make a tab active with a JS call

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, highcharts

I have a JSP page which uses bootstraps data-toggle="tab" functionality. Upon page load I make one tab active.

```
<ul class="nav st-nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">First Tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Second Tab</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1"></div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab2"></div>
</div>
```

I have a Highcharts chart on the page, whenever a user clicks on one of the columns I call a JS function which makes tab2 the active tab on the page. Inside this function I've tried a few different commands but none seem to work. I'm quite new to jQuery so I'm hoping someone might be able to point out where I'm going wrong with my syntax.

```
function handleClick(){
    //I've tried the following, none seem to work
    $('#tab2').toggleClass('active');
    $('#tab2').show();
    $('#tab2').tab('show');
}
```

Comment: Call the `.click()` method for the actual link: `$('#mynav a[href="#tab2"]').click()`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

First you need to give your tabs an `id`, i will call it myTabs:

```
<ul class="nav st-nav-tabs" id="myTabs">
```

Then you can call and show your tabs by name to show them:

```
$('#myTabs a[href="#name"]').tab('show');
```

You can read about tabs in bootstrap's [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

Comment: @180cl , you're welcome. Don't forget to mark the checkmark to the left of the answer to show it helped for future users.

Comment: From my experience, this can't be called directly from the Jquery. If you want this to work it has to be from a click or other action. this won't work: `<script> $('#myTabs a[href="#name"]').tab('show'); </script>` it needs a `click`, `done` or other actions to be activated.